# PL/SQL: catching numbered exception?

Tags: oracle, exception, plsql

Here's the canonical way to catch named exceptions.

```
  begin
      select ...;
  exception
  when zero_divide then
        ...
  end;
```

How do I catch numbered exceptions?  Can I specify several exceptional conditions in one when clause?

```
ORA-01555: snapshot too old: ...
ORA-08180: no snapshot found based on specified time
ORA-01466: unable to read data - table definition has changed
```

Comment: Use `EXCEPTION_INIT Pragma`, see this link for details and examples: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/exceptioninit_pragma.htm. See also this link: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/errors.htm#i9355 to learn basics of handling exceptions. You can specify several exception handers, just chain `WHEN .. THEN .. WHEN .. THEN..` etc.

Answer (score 1):

One possible way top of my head is write one when others handler and inside check sqlerrm(sqlcode).

```
if (sqlerrm(sqlcode) = ORA-01555) then
do this
elsif ....
```

Comment: It wouldn't have the value of `ORA-01555`, just a numeric value of `-1555`, as far as I remember https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/sqlcode_function.htm.

Comment: That is true ,, My Bad .

Comment: Well.. and your syntax is definitely non-PL/SQL. But the generally the idea is just fine.

Comment: Yeah , Last 6 Months I have been coding in Java. I will keep in mind to adhere to plsql grammar and try to post syntactically correct logic next time.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, following the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/errors.htm#i9355), we must say:

> Every exception can be associated with **only one** error code via `PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT`,
>    and many pragma declarations for the same exception gain no compilation error, but the latest pragma overrides all the previous.
>     So we have no natural (or native) PL/SQL way to joint multiple exception codes under one exception name to be able 
>   to catch them all with 
>   `WHEN my_unversal_exception THEN`.

So when we want to catch many exceptions at once, there's no other choice, but entering `WHEN OTHERS THEN` section and perform some tricks (limited only by imagination). And there's no secret - we have to deal with the `sqlcode` function, so let's do it beautiful and try to encapsulate the stuff.

One of the possible solutions: 
Create boolean functions, which check error codes (and maybe error messages), and use them as guards in `CASE TRUE WHEN ...`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE exc_filter IS 
  FUNCTION exception_kind_A RETURN boolean;
  FUNCTION exception_kind_B RETURN boolean;
  FUNCTION exception_kind_C RETURN boolean;
END;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY exc_filter IS  

  -- I use negation of sqlcode to reduce noice of minuses.

  FUNCTION exception_kind_A RETURN boolean is BEGIN
    RETURN -sqlcode IN (01476, 06502);
  END;

  FUNCTION exception_kind_B RETURN boolean IS BEGIN
    RETURN -sqlcode BETWEEN 20010 AND 20020;
  END;

  -- a bit of discouraging flexibility
  FUNCTION exception_kind_C RETURN boolean IS BEGIN
    RETURN instr(sqlerrm, 'Yay') > 0;
  END;
END;
/

DECLARE
  x number; 
BEGIN
   -- each line raises an error - uncomment to try

   x := 5/0;

   -- raise_application_error(-20008, 'Yay');

   -- raise_application_error(-20015, 'Another');

   -- x := to_number('abc');

EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN -- catch all, then switch
  CASE TRUE
  WHEN exc_filter.exception_kind_A THEN dbms_output.put_line('Kind A : ' || sqlerrm);
  WHEN exc_filter.exception_kind_B THEN dbms_output.put_line('Kind B : ' || sqlerrm);
  WHEN exc_filter.exception_kind_C THEN dbms_output.put_line('Kind C : ' || sqlerrm);
  ELSE raise; -- strongly recommended line
  END CASE; 
END;
/
```